# Any way to get current params outside a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to get the params outside of a component props?

In my case I want handle navigation inside some action creators (with redux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you connected the action createUser to your component ok?

So from your component you are going to do this:

```
this.props.createUser(this.props.username, this.props.password)
```

And finally this is going to be your action dispatcher:

```
export const createUser = (username, password) => {
  return (dispatch,getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_USER,
      username: username
    })

    browserHistory.push(`/welcome-user/${username}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited the description a bit. Overall i want to navigate based on action dispatches but, need a way to pull the params outside of the component.

Comment: So yeah, I think you should have this "params" in your global state (reducers) and then you can access your state from anywhere. I know sometimes it appears to be a lil bit of work to dispatch something to update the state, but at the end it's worth it!

Comment: I should do that manually or is it something like that already? I'm not seeing it inside of redux-router

Comment: Wait, now I think that I finally got your requirement. You want your redux-router to listen to an action, if it receives that action you want it to navigate to a route right?

Comment: yes, but still have access to the params so i can construct the proper url. right now i can only use `browserHistory.push` but have no idea of the params needed.